# Embed an MP3 in a WAV file

Tags: compression, music

Afaik, the WAV file format is just a container for multiple sound formats. Is it possible to have an MP3 embedded in a WAV file so that the file size is smaller that typical WAV files?

If so, how would one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV files are a RIFF-based container, and it's indeed possible to use different sound codecs in them. The "Sound Recorder" app in older Windows versions (built around the Windows multimedia APIs) used to do exactly that – you could select PCM, µ-Law, ADPCM, CELP, MP3, etc. but it would always use the WAV format for the file itself.

Note that it is not guaranteed to work well. Newer codecs, such as Vorbis or AAC, don't seem to work with ffmpeg-generated WAV files – the players recognize the codec, but not the actual data. I do not know the theory behind this.

There is a [list of sample files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Comparison_of_coding_schemes) on Wikipedia. You can generate them using e.g. FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i Test.mp3 -c:a copy Test.wav

ffmpeg -i TestPCM.wav -c:a libmp3lame TestMP3.wav
```

...or by using some Windows multimedia API program (such as the same sndrec32, I don't know any others) if you need encoding support for the weird old codecs.

Comment: Do you know of anything cross-platform that could actually handle one? Everything I've ever dealt with has wanted LPCM

Comment: @Tetsujin: Anything FFMPEG-based (including VLC and to some extent GStreamer). About the only thing they can't decode is L&H's CELP and SBC, but they recognize the sample MP3 or TrueSpeech or ADPCM files just fine.