# Ffmpeg can't read wav file created with Naudio

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-22.04

I have created a wav file using Naudio on Ubuntu 22.04. When I run ffmpeg -i mywav.wav ffmpeg states "no data tag found" although on inspection I find the data tag at indexes 38-41. When I look at the audio properties thru file manager it states that it is a wav container with mp3 codec.

[image: screenshot of file manger properties]

Most audio programs such as vlc and audacity seem to be unable to read this wav file but it is readable using the default video player(videos).
I've googled this pretty intensively and can't seem to understand why this occurs.
[this link states embedding an mp3 in a wav container is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1460297/embed-an-mp3-in-a-wav-file).
Hopefully someone here understands what's going on and why ffmpeg and some audio players can't recognize this wav file.
[Here is the wav file if anyone would care to inspect it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVH6kF3dJP2oJyT2akMz-uRt6qy7lS_J/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: On Win 10 Media player, Total Commander play it w/o problem. foobar, vlc not. Xrecode successfully recode it in flac. Seems like the `WAV` format is odd

Comment: Is it possible that the filename extension just needs to be changed from .wav to .mp3?

Comment: @Davey: No, I just tested `cp mywav.wav mywav.mp3; ffmpeg -i mywav.mp3 test.mp3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will qualify as an answer but...

On **Windows 11** running the latest version of Audacity I ***can*** successfully import this file. I can also open it successfully in MPC-HC.

If I attempt to input this file into FFmpeg it does fail stating there is no 'data' tag. This might be causing FFmpeg to get confused by the container.

Starting a terminal and running the following FFmpeg command I was able to open and transcode your mywav.wav to FLAC as mywav.mka (Matroska Audio container).

```
ffmpeg -f mp3 -i "mywav.wav" -c:a flac "mywav.mka"
```

Here we are telling FFmpeg with `-f mp3` that our input file is actually an mp3.

Give that a try.

As a note, you can also try changing the format or container you're exporting in; it might solve this altogether.

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your help in resolving the ffmpeg issue.